# how to find out how many items are selected in select box

Tags: javascript

I have a select box which has more than 200 items.

Below the select box is the submit button which submits the form using javascript.

I want to restrict the user to only select 100 items from the select box. If they select box and try to submit the form then it will say `Select 100 Only`

How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Similar question about limiting the # of selections in a select list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600770/how-can-i-get-the-last-selected-value-in-a-listbox-with-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either:

Loop through all of the options elements and check the selected attribute:

```
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < selectbox.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectbox.options[i].selected === true) {
        cnt++;
    }
}

return cnt;
```

Or you can get the `value` of the select element and split the value by comma and base it on the number of items in the array.

```
var vlu = selectbox.value;
var vlus = vlu.split(',');

return vlus.length;
```

Comment: you currently have assignment in the if-statement.